# ssh host key certificates, find validity period remotely?

Tags: ssh, monitoring

I have an environment where I use ssh certificates to authenticate ssh host keys. I'm talking about the kind of certificates created by running `ssh-keygen -s /path/to/ca -h ...`. These certificates are also created with a validity interval, stating when they will expire. These certificates have now been in use now long enough that I need to start monitor them, to get a heads up when they start getting close to expire.

Any way I can do a remote connection, without logging in, and somehow either get the validity interval displayed alt. get the certificate downloaded? Running `ssh -vvv` don't appear to display the info I need. Neither does `ssh-keyscan` appear to be certificate aware. Perhaps some library I haven't looked closely enough at?

Worst case I can always write a monitoring plugin which runs locally and parses the output of `ssh-keygen -L -f`. Still, a remote scan really feels like the preferable approach.

Comment: Comparing the output of `ssh -vvv` with a certified host key to what it looks like with an ordinary host key could provide some clue as to where to start looking for an answer.

Comment: It does not, only the fingerprint gets printed.

Comment: openssl s_client -showcerts would work for a web server. I don't have an ssh server with a cert based key to test it on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Edit: OpenSSH 7.2 introduced tool support in the form of the new `-c` flag for the `ssh-keyscan` command. The rest of this answer was written more than a year before that release, but I'm keeping it here because I'm proud of it.)

This is possible, but it lacks tool support. I found a library which speaks the SSH protocol well enough to let me write a tool to extract the host cert valid_before time without a full ssh login. Here it is, in the Go language. I hope it helps.

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
import "fmt"
import "os"
import "time"

func ignoreCertChain(auth ssh.PublicKey, address string) bool {
    return true // Pretend all certificates are trusted.
}

var sawACert bool

func examineCert(cert *ssh.Certificate) bool {
  expires := cert.ValidBefore
  var humanReadable string
  if expires >= ssh.CertTimeInfinity {
    humanReadable = "infinity"
  } else if expires < (1 << 63) {
    humanReadable = time.Unix(int64(expires), 0).Format(time.RFC3339)
  } else {
    humanReadable = "the distant future"
  }
  fmt.Println("Cert expires at time", expires, "(" + humanReadable + ")")
  sawACert = true
  return true  // Reject the cert, to force early connection close.
}

func main() {
  serverHostPort := os.Args[1]
  checker := &ssh.CertChecker{
    IsHostAuthority: ignoreCertChain,
    IsRevoked: examineCert,
  }
  config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: "test-sshcertscan-not-a-real-login-attempt",
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
      ssh.Password(""),
    },
    HostKeyCallback: checker.CheckHostKey,
  }
  sawACert = false
  client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", serverHostPort, config);
  if err != nil && !sawACert {
    panic(fmt.Sprint("Cannot connect to ", serverHostPort, ", error: ",
                     err.Error()))
  } else if client != nil {
    defer client.Close()
  }
}
```

(Quick usage instructions: install [Go](http://golang.org/doc/install), save the code seen above in sshcertscan.go, run `go build sshcertscan.go`, then point it at an ssh server on examplehost port 22 with `./sshcertscan examplehost:22`.)

Comment: Wow, also writing that example code certainly went way over and beyond, thanks! Now I just need to learn a bit more go :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know of any open-source tool. It seems nmap would be able to retrieve it somehow with [NSE](https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/scripts/ssl-cert.nse) scripts (but needs some tweaking -- check /usr/share/nmap/scripts).

SSH's [Tectia SSH](http://www.ssh.com/products/tectia-ssh) server includes a tool called ssh-fetchkey that will retrieve the certificate and then you can use ssh-certview to view the details.

Comment: While I might not use NSE scripts for this purpose, it definitely sounds like something I might find future uses for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following command will get the certificate and display information about it:

```
ssh-keyscan -c <host> | ssh-keygen -L  -f -
```

example output:

```
        Type: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com host certificate
        Public key: ED25519-CERT SHA256:XXX<redacted>
        Signing CA: ED25519 SHA256:XXX<redacted>
        Key ID: "my_server"
        Serial: 0
        Valid: from 2022-12-05T15:42:00 to 2023-12-04T15:43:35
        Principals: 
                my_server.example.com
                my_server
                www.example.com
        Critical Options: (none)
        Extensions: (none)
```

Comment: ... since 7.2, which was 2 years after the Q was asked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the answer is "that's not possible". At least not in any way I found, using either the openssh client or the paramiko SSH library for python. I would suggest a local check as you described, combined with a simpler remote check that verifies that the key used by SSHD is the key you just checked the certificate lifetime of.